# Turtles Errors and Exceptions

Tags: python, exception

I am a senior high school student and have  been working with python for the last few months.
I completed this program which draws squares to the screen and the user can input the size, color and number of squares. I asked my teacher on how I can further improve this program and he mentioned errors and exceptions. I partially implemented it into my code but it does not seem to be right. He suggested looking on this site for answers and possible help. I appreciate any advice and guidance.

```
import turtle 
window = turtle.Screen()
elon = turtle.Turtle()
varX = -175
varY = 200
elon.penup()
userPenSize = input("Hey what size pen do you want?" "(0-10) ")
#^ asking user the size of pen they would like
userColor = input("What color do you want? " "(blue, yellow, orange, pink) ")
#^ asking user the color pen they want to use
hmTri = input("How many triangles do you want? ")
#^ asking user how many squares they want drawn to screen
for bigCount in range(int(hmTri)): #input from user of how many squares will be drawn 
Exception (ValueError)
print ("Could not convert data to an integer.")
elon.goto(varX, varY)
elon.pendown()
for smallCount in range(4):
elon.pensize(int(userPenSize)) #input from user for pen size
Exception (ValueError)
print ("Could not convert data to an integer.")
elon.pencolor(str(userColor)) #input from user for pen color
elon.forward(100)
elon.right(90)
varX = varX + 50 #moving 50 pixels on x axis each square
varY = varY - 50 #moving -50 pixels on y axis each square
elon.penup()
```

Comment: "It does not seem to be right" is not an accurate enough description of your problem. If you get an error, please include the complete error traceback in your question. If your program doesn't produce what you expect, explain what the output is vs your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "try... except..." like below,

```
try:
    hmTri = input("How many triangles do you want? ")
    num = int(hmTri)
except ValueError:
    # maybe input "Hello World"
    print('Only input numbers')
except:
    # other wrong format
    print('Something Wrong')
```